# Implementing multiple constructors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a program that deals with rational numbers that may be represented as either:

- a fraction
- a prime factorisation

What I have in mind is to establish a single class `Rational` which could represent a rational number given either a fraction or a prime factorisation. In this sense, I am looking for something akin to having multiple constructors for this class, for each context. My initial sense was to use `static` blocks to generate the missing information, like this:

```js
const primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47];

class Factors {
    constructor(powers, remainderNum, remainderDen) {
        // powers is an array of powers of only those primes listed above
        // remainder is a fraction of the remainder (if none then just{1,1})
        this.powers = powers;
        this.remainder = {
            num: remainderNum,
            den: remainderDen
        };
    }
}

class Fraction {
    constructor(num, den) {
        this.num = num;
        this.den = den;
    }
}

class Rational {
    constructor(factors, fraction) {
        this.factors = factors;
        this.fraction = fraction;
    }
    // Instantiation via factors 
    static ViaFactors(factors) {
        function getFraction(factors) {
            let powers = factors.powers;
            let num = factors.remainder.num;
            let den = factors.remainder.den;
            for (let i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
                if (powers[i] > 0) {
                    num *= Math.pow(primes[i], powers[i]);
                } else {
                    den *= Math.pow(primes[i], Math.abs(powers[i]));
                }
            }
            return new Fraction(num, den);
        }
        return new Rational(factors, getFraction(factors));
    }
    // Instantiation via a fraction
    static ViaFraction(fraction) {
        function getFactors(fraction) {
            let powers = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
            let num = fraction.num;
            let den = fraction.den;
            for (let i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
                while (num % primes[i] == 0) {
                    powers[i]++;
                    num /= primes[i];
                }
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
                while (den % primes[i] == 0) {
                    powers[i]--;
                    den /= primes[i];
                }
            }
            return new Factors(powers, num, den);
        }
        return new Rational(getFactors(fraction), fraction);
    }    
}

// Testing

const powers = new Factors(
    [0,-2,-1,0,0,0,-2,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
    53,
    1
);
const fraction = new Fraction(52417, 13005);
const ratio1 = Rational.ViaFactors(powers);
const ratio2 = Rational.ViaFraction(fraction);

console.log(`via factors:
rat ${ratio1.fraction.num}/${ratio1.fraction.den}
pow (${ratio1.factors.powers}) 
rem ${ratio1.factors.remainder.num}/${ratio1.factors.remainder.den}`);

console.log(`via fraction:
rat ${ratio2.fraction.num}/${ratio2.fraction.den}
pow (${ratio2.factors.powers})
rem ${ratio2.factors.remainder.num}/${ratio2.factors.remainder.den}`);
```

Basically, this works as you can see.

This is how I would probably approach this in Java or Kotlin, but I'm wondering if this is the best approach in JavaScript?

Comment: "Best approach" veers quickly into opinion. I wouldn't name functions like they're classes; they're just factories, but other than that, I wouldn't have any problems with this approach if I saw it IRL.

Comment: your code is fine, except  the factories would look better as `fromFactors` and `fromFraction` and instead of `new Rational` you really should use `new this` to support extensions.